# RequestScoped bean created/destroyed multiple times during a single request

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I'm observing that my requestScoped bean described below, is being created multiple times during a single request. Each time the bean is reinstantiated, just a small time ago the bean had been destroyed, as per the logs say.

```
@ManagedBean(name="namesDirectory")
@RequestScoped
public class NamesDirectory {

    public static NamesDirectory getCurrentInstance(){
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();            
        return context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{namesDirectory}", NamesDirectory.class);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void foo(){
        Easy.log("bean created");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void foo1(){
        Easy.log("bean destroyed");
    }

}
```

What could be the reason for the bean being destroyed before all the processing of the single request is completed & how do I take care of not letting this thing happen ?

---

## Edit:

I had `<p:graphicImage url="#" />` at some places in my facelets code that caused requests to be triggered multiple times. After removing these I am still seeing this request created but just two times where previously it was many more times.

Actually I am seeing this while attempting login in to my application. So  after  the credentials are supplied & they are verified, the bean is instantiated & used but it is after this that the user is moved to a successful login page &  during building of which the bean is again needed, so it is created as it is non existent. This causes this request scoped bean to be created 2 times, for what I believe, is just a single request.

Answer (score 1):

Your login is probably redirecting the browser to a new page with a `Location:` header, which is very normal. So you should expect two requests and hence two request-scoped beans. Likewise, as you noticed, linked images cause another browser request. This is just how the web works. If it bothers you that much, you can use a different scope (e.g. session, so one bean per logged-in user) but be careful with tabbed browsing.